# C# Linq spare a double foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I have a double foreach loop which I wonder if could be spared with some clever use of Linq.

So I have a geometric shape, which is defined by a collection of polygons, where polygons are a collection of vertices.

I want to calculate the average of the vertices. Here is my code, which works fine, but I feel like it could be a lot prettier using Linq. However I could not figure out a way to do it. Can anyone help?

```
HashSet<Vector2> vertices = new HashSet<Vector2>();

// This double foreach is what I want to get using Linq if it is even possible.
foreach (var polygon in polygons.Select(a => a.points))
{
    foreach (var vertex in polygon)
    {
        vertices.Add(vertex);
    }
}

Vector2 c = new Vector2(0, 0);
foreach (var vertex in vertices)
{
    c += vertex;
}

c.X = c.X / vertices.Count;
c.Y = c.Y / vertices.Count;
this.center = c;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
polygons.SelectMany(p => p.Points).Distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SelectMany` LINQ method. With `HashSet.UnionWith` you don't even need `Distinct` call:

```
var vertices = new HashSet<Vector2>();
verticles.UnionWith(polygons.SelectMany(x => x.points))
```

You can also use LINQ to replace the second `foreach` loop:

```
var c = verticles.Aggregate(new Vertor2(0,0), (v,x) => v += x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This will result in an enumerable, but you can also do [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which results in a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var vertices = polygons
    .SelectMany(x => x.points)
    .ToList();
```